# How to create in table list with customer JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i have big problem with JavaScript, i am beginner and i want to create simple list with people and product list. So i create name customers, product list, and it's make shopping, but i want to show in table what can buy each person, and how many money he will spend:

**My code after UPDATE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>!DOCTYPE</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <script>

var buyerList = [];
buyerList[0] = createBuyer('Jon', 20000)
buyerList[1] = createBuyer('Will', 25000)
buyerList[2] = createBuyer('Tom', 10000)

var productList = [];
productList[0] = createProduct('mp3', 3500)
productList[1] = createProduct('Meizu', 9000)
productList[2] = createProduct('Iphone', 25000)
productList[3] = createProduct('Philips', 16000)

var buyer;

for (var i = 0; i < buyerList.length; i++) {
  buyer = buyerList[i];
  buyer['basket'] = shoping(buyer['wallet'])
}

showResult(buyerList);

/***********LIBRARY**************/

function createBuyer(arg_name, arg_wallet, arg_gender = 'boy') {
  if (arg_wallet < 0)
    arg_wallet = 0
  return {
    name: arg_name,
    wallet: arg_wallet,
    gender: arg_gender
  }
}

function createProduct(arg_name, arg_price) {
  return {
    name: arg_name,
    price: arg_price
  }
}

function shoping(wallet) {
  var tovar;
  var basket = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
    tovar = productList[i];
    if (wallet > tovar['price']) {
      basket.push(tovar);
      wallet -= tovar['price']
    }
  }

  return basket;
}

function showResult(buyerslist) {
  var result = '<table align="center" width="400" bgcolor="#ffcc00">';
    for(buyer of buyerslist){
        var rowspan=Object.keys(buyer.basket).length+1;
        result+='<tr><td rowspan='+rowspan+'>'+buyer.name+'</td>';
        result+='<td rowspan='+rowspan+'>'+buyer.wallet+'</td>';
        result+='<td rowspan='+rowspan+'>'+buyer.gender+'</td></tr>';
        for(var item of buyer.basket){
          result+='<tr><td>'+item.name+'</td><td>'+item.price+'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
  result+='</table>';
  document.getElementById("details").innerHTML=result;
}
 </script>
 <body>
<div id="details">

 </body> 
</html>
```

As you can see function showResult it's not correct, i really tired to find solution.
In func showResult i want to get the table with list of customers, and which product they can buy, and how many money they will spend

Comment: What kind of result did you expect ?

Comment: In func showResult i want to get the table with list of customers, and which product they can buy, and how many money they will spend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. As @Ivan pointed out, avoid using `document.write`.

```js
var buyerList = [];
buyerList[0] = createBuyer('Jon', 20000)
buyerList[1] = createBuyer('Will', 25000)
buyerList[2] = createBuyer('Tom', 10000)

var productList = [];
productList[0] = createProduct('mp3', 3500)
productList[1] = createProduct('Meizu', 9000)
productList[2] = createProduct('Iphone', 25000)
productList[3] = createProduct('Philips', 16000)

var buyer;

for (var i = 0; i < buyerList.length; i++) {
  buyer = buyerList[i];
  buyer['basket'] = shoping(buyer['wallet'])
}

showResult(buyerList);

/***********LIBRARY**************/

function createBuyer(arg_name, arg_wallet, arg_gender = 'boy') {
  if (arg_wallet < 0)
    arg_wallet = 0
  return {
    name: arg_name,
    wallet: arg_wallet,
    gender: arg_gender
  }
}

function createProduct(arg_name, arg_price) {
  return {
    name: arg_name,
    price: arg_price
  }
}

function shoping(wallet) {
  var tovar;
  var basket = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
    tovar = productList[i];
    if (wallet > tovar['price']) {
      basket.push(tovar);
      wallet -= tovar['price']
    }
  }

  return basket;
}

function showResult(buyerslist) {
  var result = '<table align="center" width="400" bgcolor="#ffcc00">';
    for(buyer of buyerslist){
        var rowspan=Object.keys(buyer.basket).length+1;
        result+='<tr><td rowspan='+rowspan+'>'+buyer.name+'</td>';
        result+='<td rowspan='+rowspan+'>'+buyer.wallet+'</td>';
        result+='<td rowspan='+rowspan+'>'+buyer.gender+'</td></tr>';
        for(var item of buyer.basket){
          result+='<tr><td>'+item.name+'</td><td>'+item.price+'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
  result+='</table>';
  document.getElementById("details").innerHTML=result;
}
```

```html
<div id="details">
```

Comment: ... and you should avoid using `innerHTML +=` on rendered elements

Comment: where i need to put the **<div id="details">**

Comment: @qunzi Just add it in the html where you want to display the table.

Comment: I update question with my full code, and i don't know where i need put  **<div id="details">**

Comment: Its already correct. You need to put the elements in your body.

Comment: Can i get example?

Comment: What do u mean by example? I don't get your point. Its already working right ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at showResult

Comment: Try adding the script after the body tag. Script must execute after DOM content has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing the content with [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) which will **overwrite the page content** every time you call it. You need to create an HTML element, append some content to it, then append it to the document.

Here's how you can do it:

1. create a new object of type HTMLElement with the method [`.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement):

   ```
   const element= document.createElement('div')
   ```
2. Fill the element with HTML string by accessing the property [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of your element:

   ```
   element.innerHTML = "<div>Some more html</div>"
   ```
3. When you're done filling the table, append the element to an existing DOM element

   ```
   document.querySelector('body').appendChild(element)
   ```

---

So with that in mind, we can work on displaying all your objects in an HTML table:

1. create a new HTML element of tag `div` and save it in a variable `table`:

   ```
   const table = document.createElement('div');
   ```
2. prepare the content of your table by using the [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method on the array.

   ```
   const tableContent = list.reduce((string, e) => string + `
    <tr>
      <td>${e.name}</td>
      <td>${e.wallet}</td>
      <td>${e.gender}</td>
    </tr>
   `, '');
   ```
3. add the content to the table's [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property:

   ```
    table.innerHTML = `
     <table align="center" width="800" bgcolor="#ffcc00">
       <tr><th>Name</th><th>Name</th><th>Gender</th></tr>
       ${tableContent}
     </table>
   `;
   ```
4. Append the table to the `body`:

   ```
   document.querySelector('body').appendChild(table)
   ```

---

The full code will look like:

```js
var buyerList = [];
buyerList[0] = createBuyer('Jon', 20000)
buyerList[1] = createBuyer('Will', 25000)
buyerList[2] = createBuyer('Tom', 10000)

function createBuyer(arg_name, arg_wallet, arg_gender = 'boy') {
  return {
    name: arg_name,
    wallet: (arg_wallet < 0) ? 0 : arg_wallet,
    gender: arg_gender
  }
}

showResult(buyerList);

function showResult(list) {

  const table = document.createElement('div');
  const tableContent = list.reduce((string, e) => string + `
    <tr>
      <td>${e.name}</td>
      <td>${e.wallet}</td>
      <td>${e.gender}</td>
    </tr>
  `, '');
  
  table.innerHTML = `
    <table align="center" width="800" bgcolor="#ffcc00">
      <tr><th>Name</th><th>Name</th><th>Gender</th></tr>
      ${tableContent}
    </table>
  `;
  
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(table)

}
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

If you don't know [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) well here's an alternative using a [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop:

```js
let HTMLString = '';
list.forEach(e => HTMLString + `
 <tr>
   <td>${e.name}</td>
   <td>${e.wallet}</td>
   <td>${e.gender}</td>
 </tr>
`);
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token with this row td {
  text-align: center;
}

Comment: Thanks, but i want to show what person can buy from the product list

Comment: I have shown you how it can be done. Now it's time for **you** to try and make it work. Coding is not about copying/pasting...